# Error API key not found when i am trying to add google map to Xamarin

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin

I'm trying to add Google Maps in Xamarin Forms app but when I run it
this error occurred:

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException
>    Message=API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml'

[Erorr message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBvgX.png)

Is there any way to know this API is active?

Comment: actually showing us your manifest would be helpful

Comment: erorr message https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBvgX.png

Comment: @ghaith Not looking for the error (you already have that listed), we are looking for your android manifest and how you added the key to it.

Comment: Please do NOT post code or errors as images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure, it is inside the application element and they spelling is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check this docs page: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api#-specify-the-required-permissions

Scroll down a bit to the large code block after "The following snippet is an example of the settings that must be added to AndroidManifest.XML:" and make sure to replace YOUR_API_KEY with your actual api key.

Copied from link (in case it goes away):

```
The following snippet is an example of the settings that must be added to AndroidManifest.XML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:versionName="4.5" 
          package="com.xamarin.docs.android.mapsandlocationdemo2" 
          android:versionCode="6">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

    <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 requires OpenGL ES v2 -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

    <!-- Necessary for apps that target Android 9.0 or higher -->
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />


    <!-- Permission to receive remote notifications from Google Play Services -->
    <!-- Notice here that we have the package name of our application as a prefix on the permissions. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="<PACKAGE NAME>.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="<PACKAGE NAME>.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- These are optional, but recommended. They will allow Maps to use the My Location provider. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <!-- Put your Google Maps V2 API Key here. -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!-- Necessary for apps that target Android 9.0 or higher -->
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API keys can be found in your Google Cloud Platform Console

Here's the link : https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

You can check for the status of your "Maps SDK for Android" by searching for it in the GCP console's API Library : https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library